# Button Text Change in UWP application C# outside of button_click

Tags: c#, button, uwp

I am new to UWP applications and c# in general.

I am trying to change a buttons text after another button on a different page has been pressed, whats the best approach for doing this?

I cant seem to find an valuable answer online.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of ways to pass data between pages, one way to achieve this is to use something called the sender parameter usually marked as e which you probably noticed in events, I've made a simple example on how to use it check it out:

1. I've created a page and added a button called Page1Button that changes it's content once clicked.

   ```
   private void Page1Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       Page1Button.Content = "Clicked";
   }
   ```
2. I've created another button on this page that will navigate to the second page and called the button NextPage and the page I named Page2.

   ```
   private void NextPage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       string Button_State = "";
       if (Page1Button.Content == "Clicked")
       {
           Button_State = "Clicked";
       }
       this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), Button_State);
   }
   ```
3. Now on Page2 I've added a button I named Page2Button that will change it's content if the "Button_State" string is set to clicked under an event called OnNavigatedTo.

   ```
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
       string Button_State = (string) e.Parameter;
       if (Button_State == "Clicked")
       {
           Page2Button.Content = "The button was pressed";
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just needed that simple explanation, its always difficult making heads or tails of things when your starting out. Much appreciated.

Comment: glad I could help ;)